# trigger handler populating Contact email address on Opportunity custom field Primary_Email__c doesn't change the email when updating the Contact

Tags: apex, trigger

The below code works fine when I insert a new Contact with email. But when I update the Exchange Contact field on Opportunity it still keeps the email of the previous Contact. Please help me to resolve the issue.

```
public with sharing class PrimaryEmailOnExchange {
    public static void populatePrimaryEmailOnExchange(List<Opportunity> oppList) {

        Set<Id> conIds = new Set<Id>();

        for (Opportunity oppt : oppList) {
            if(oppt.Exchange_Contact__c != null){
                conIds.add(oppt.Exchange_Contact__c);
            }

        }

        Map<Id, Contact> mapCont = new Map<Id, Contact>([
                SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Id IN : conIds
        ]);

        for (Opportunity oppt : oppList) {
            if (oppt.Exchange_Contact__c != null && oppt.Primary_Email__c == null) {
                    if (mapCont.containsKey(oppt.Exchange_Contact__c)) {
                        Contact c = mapCont.get(oppt.Exchange_Contact__c);
                        oppt.Primary_Email__c = c.Email;
                        oppt.ContactId = c.Id;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And Trigger:

```
trigger populatePrimaryEmailOnExchange on Opportunity (before insert, before update, after update) {

    if (Trigger.isBefore || Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
        PrimaryEmailOnExchange.populatePrimaryEmailOnExchange(Trigger.new);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is explicitly taking no action if the `Primary_Email__c` field is populated, which would be the case if you changed an existing value in the `Exchange_Contact__c` field:

```
if (oppt.Exchange_Contact__c != null && oppt.Primary_Email__c == null) {
```

You'll likely want to change this to something like

```
if (oppt.Exchange_Contact__c != null 
    && mapCont.containsKey(oppt.Exchange_Contact__c) 
    && oppt.Primary_Email__c != mapCont.get(oppt.Exchange_Contact__c).Email) {
```

so that you take action if and only if a change is required.

That said, this could easily just be a formula field.

Comment: I kind of was leaning towards a "they allow manual overrides" situation, because otherwise a formula would make sense, but this may be a valid solution, too (p.s. if Exchange_Contact__c != null, the map contains the key).